# Script is only going to last text and last color but is animating as directed, what's going on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am able to move the text around the div like I would like but I want it to be different colors and have different *text/colors* at different parts of the movement but it is only calling the final text and colors. The `'slow'` part of the jQuery function seems to only be firing for the first part of the movement.

What am I doing wrong?

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/9em93bc4/2/)

HTML:

```
<button id="button">Go!</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="container">    
<div id="demo">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
   width: 100%;
   height: 400px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').on('click', function(){
        var divWidth = ($('#container').width());
        var divHeight = ($('#container').height());
        $('#demo').css('color', '#ffff00');
        $('#demo').html("Going!");
        $('#demo').animate({
        'marginLeft' : '+=' + divWidth
        }, ' slow');
        $('#demo').html("Moving Down Now");
        $('#demo').css('color', '#e31912');
        $('#demo').animate({
        'marginTop' : '+=' + divHeight
        }, ' slow');
        $('#demo').html("Moving Home Now");
        $('#demo').css('color', '#00FFFF');
        $('#demo').animate({
        'marginLeft' : '-=' + divWidth,
        'marginTop' : '-=' + divHeight,
        }, ' slow');
        $('#demo').html("I am home!");
        $('#demo').css('color', '#ff0067');

    });
});
```

Comment: look into adding [delays](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) that allow your text and color to be fired in sync with the animation.

Comment: You can also use the ["complete"](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) parameter to execute your functions after an animation has completed.

Comment: Works as expected, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While animations are queued by default, changes made with the `css()` and `html()` methods do not wait for your animations to be complete. They are all executed immediately, without any delay, and all you see is the last setting.

Rather than nesting animations, I suggest that you chain them. Then use the "start" and "complete" [callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#callbacks) to set HTML and CSS. The callbacks will be executed before and after each animation, respectively.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#button').on('click', function() {

    var divWidth = 300,
      divHeight = 100;

    // stage #1
    $('#demo').animate({
      'marginLeft': '+=' + divWidth
    }, {
      duration: 'slow',
      start: function() {
        $(this).css('color', '#128800').html("Going!");
      }
    })

    // stage #2
    .animate({
      'marginTop': '+=' + divHeight
    }, {
      duration: 'slow',
      start: function() {
        $(this).css('color', '#e31912').html("Moving Down Now");
      }
    })

    // stage #3
    .animate({
      'marginLeft': '-=' + divWidth,
      'marginTop': '-=' + divHeight,
    }, {
      duration: 'slow',
      start: function() {
        $(this).css('color', '#3cacac').html("Moving Home Now");
      },
      complete: function() {
        $(this).css('color', '#ff0067').html("I am home!");
      }
    });

  });

});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Go!</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="container">
  <div id="demo">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to wait until the animate script is finished:

```
`$('#demo').animate({
    'marginLeft' : '+=' + divWidth
    }, ' slow', function(){
....
});`
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xzzc4skq/1/

Answer (score 2):

`.animate()` is asynchronous. The animations appear in order because the animate function appends the animation to a queue. You can use the optional callback parameter of `.animate()` to avoid this.

([**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9em93bc4/3/))

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').on('click', function(){
        var demo = $('#demo');
        var divWidth = $('#container').width();
        var divHeight = $('#container').height();
        demo.css('color', '#ffff00').text("Going!").animate({
            'marginLeft' : '+=' + divWidth
        }, 'slow', function(){
            demo.css('color','#e31912').text("Moving Down Now").animate({
                'marginTop' : '+=' + divHeight
            }, 'slow', function(){
                demo.css('color', '#00FFFF').html("Moving Home Now").animate({
                    'marginLeft' : '-=' + divWidth,
                    'marginTop' : '-=' + divHeight,
                }, 'slow', function(){
                    demo.css('color', '#ff0067').html("I am home!");
                });
            });
        });

    });
});
```